# Did the Daleks kill Davros?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

I read that the Daleks from Doctor Who put their creator, Davros, on trial. Does anyone know if they killed him, or at least what happened to him afterward?

Comment: Where/when did this happen? In a TV episode, novel, comic, Big Finish audio, ... ?

Comment: i read that they did this in a TV episode on wikipedia, when I was doing research on them.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the information you found then? It would be helpful to know where to search for this.

Comment: [*The Trial of Davros*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial_of_Davros) (theatrical production)? [*The Davros Mission*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Davros_Mission) (audio play)?

Comment: I think OP is referring to the end of the episode *[Revelation of the Daleks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_of_the_Daleks)*, but they would need to clarify that themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens in the Sixth Doctor story *Revelation of the Daleks*, broadcast in two parts in March 1985. From [Wikipedia's plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_of_the_Daleks):

> Daleks loyal to the Dalek Supreme arrive from Skaro, called by Takis who now realises what has been going on. Takis leads the grey Skaro Daleks to Davros' laboratory, where they are met by cream and gold Necros Daleks who are loyal only to Davros. A battle ensues, during which Davros' only usable hand is shot off by Orcini. The grey Daleks then take Davros to Skaro to stand trial.

However, the audio story *[The Juggernauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Juggernauts)*, first released in 2005, revealed that **Davros never actually stood trial** - the prison ship that was carrying him crash-landed on the planet Lethe, allowing Davros to escape his captors. So no, the Daleks didn't kill him or do anything else to him, because they never got the chance.

It's worth noting that the Daleks *have* attempted to kill Davros on multiple other occasions. Notably, the first story he appears in, *[Genesis of the Daleks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_of_the_Daleks)*, ends with him being shot and seemingly killed by his own creations when they realise he is not a Dalek himself and thus "impure". However, *Revelation of the Daleks* was the only time they attempted to make him stand trial.

Comment: okay, thanks! this has helped my studies of doctor who significantly!